# using MongoHQ and PHPFog

Tags: ssh, nosql, cloud-hosting

newbie here. I m confused.  I want to know how I could use MongoDB through MongoHQ with an app hosted on PHPFog. Phpfog uses Github to push  commits in your base folder. Thank you!

Comment: I guess if I would ask this question again in 2 years people could answer me.

Comment: I don't think you are missing answers because people cannot answer you, I think you question is very vague, what exactly do you wish to know?

Answer (score 2):

Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongo.php to use MongoDB from PHP.

Log in to MongoHQ and create a database. Get the connection URL, which should be something like this:

`mongodb://<user>:<password>@flame.mongohq.com:27101/testing`

Then use this line in PHP to connect to the database:

`$m = new Mongo("mongodb://<user>:<password>@flame.mongohq.com:27101");`

Remember to remove the /testing at the end of the connection URL.

Answer (score 1):

log into your phpfog account select the app you want mongoHQ DB on. Click "add-ons" and select MongoHQ.  that simple :)